# Representation of integers as quadratic forms with integer coefficients

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms, theta-functions, representations-by-quadratic-forms

While reading the book *The sensual (quadratic) form* by J.H. Conway I got curious in this question. Maybe it is trivial, but I don't know how to answer it.

Let $f(x,y)=ax^2+hxy+by^2$, $g(x,y)=a'x^2+h'xy+b'y^2$ be two positive definite quadratic forms with integer coefficients $a,b,h,a',b',h'\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $N_f(n)$ be the number of representations of an integer $n\ge 0$ by the quadratic form $f(x,y)$:

$$
N_f(n)=\left\{\text{#}~{\rm{of}}~x,y\in\mathbb{Z}~ {\rm such~ that}~n=f(x,y) \right\}.
$$

> Q: Are there two positive definite quadratic forms $f$ and $g$ with integer coefficients such that 
>   $1)~N_f(n)=N_g(n)$ for all integers $n\ge 0$ and 
>   $2)~f$ and $ g$ are not related by a transformation $x\to Ax$, $A\in {SL_2(Z)}$.

Comment: It'd be good to put the "for any matrix A" in the front of condition 2, i.e., "(2) there exists *no* integer matrix $A$ with the property that ..." As written, it's easy -- take just about any two forms, like $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1}$ and $\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1}$, and $A = \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}$ as a counterexample. I realize this is a counterexample to what you wrote rather than what you intended, of course. (It'd probably be a good idea to add quantifiers to $x$ and $y$ as well.)

Comment: So you meant $f,g$ are not isomorphic (not related by a transformation $x\mapsto A x, A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$)

Comment: @reuns, yes, that's correct.

Comment: @JohnHughes I corrected it, thanks.

Comment: If we know the map $n \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mapsto f(n,n)$ then we can use the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) to recover the map $(n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mapsto f(n,m)$ that we can extend to $(n,m)\in \mathbb{Q}^2$ and hence to $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Thus the question is how $N_f$ determinates the map $n \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mapsto f(n,n)$ (I'd say it does up to a transformation $n \mapsto A n, A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$)

Comment: @Trell is this out of the realm of pell-type equations? $$f(x,y)=ax^2+hxy+by^2 \qquad \implies$$
$$f(x,y)=a\left(x+\frac{h}{2a}y\right)^2-\left(\frac{h^2-4ab}{4a}\right)y^2$$
For one $(x_0,y_0)$ set
$$\alpha=ax_0^2+hx_0y_0+by_0^2$$
Wish to find all $(x,y)$ such that

$$f(x,y)=a\left(x+\frac{h}{2a}y\right)^2-\left(\frac{h^2-4ab}{4a}\right)y^2=\alpha$$
Or
$$a\left(2ax+hy\right)^2-a\left(h^2-4ab\right)y^2=4a^2\alpha$$
$$\left(2ax+hy\right)^2-\left(h^2-4ab\right)y^2=4a\alpha$$
$$t^2-\beta\cdot y^2=4a\alpha \qquad | \qquad (\beta=h^2-4ab) \qquad (t=2ax+hy)$$

Comment: @reuns is this a difficult question, more proper to ask at mathoverflow?

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy I think this is not related to Pell equation, because Pell equation does not involve positive def forms.

Comment: $$\underline{t^2-\beta\cdot y^2=4a\alpha} \qquad \bigg{|} \qquad (\beta=h^2-4ab) \qquad (t=2ax+hy)\implies \left(x=\frac{t-hy}{2a}\right)$$
Same would go for g.and the question is changed to whether the two pells have the same number of solutions?

Comment: @Tyrell  hmm ok that was my first instinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no. If two positive binary forms agree, including representation counts, they are the same or "opposite." So, as you wrote $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ instead of $GL_2 \mathbb Z,$ the one bit of wiggle room is given by pairs such as
$$ 2 x^2 + xy + 3 y^2, \; \; \;  2 x^2 - xy + 3 y^2  $$

See page 45 in Conway's book, sketch of proof for binary forms.

The same thing happens in three variables, although in odd dimension we cannot distinguish effectively between positive and negative determinant in "equivalence." This should be in the book somewhere, [result of my co-author Alexander Schiemann](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Schiemann_1997_Annalen.pdf). Alexander also found the first example in dimension 4, two distinct forms with same representation counts. From
[Nipp 1708-1732](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/d1732.html)

```
d      g  f11 f22 f33 f44 f12 f13 f23 f14 f24 f34   H         N      G   m1   m2
1729  4:   2   4   4   5   1   0   1   1   3   4 ; -1 1-1 1  1729    2  703   48
1729  4:   2   4   5   5   2   1  -2   1   1   5 ; -1 1-1 1  1729    2  703   48


  [ 2f11   f12   f13   f14 ]
  [ f12   2f22   f23   f24 ]
  [ f13   f23   2f33   f34 ]
  [ f14   f24   f34   2f44 ]


 In the discriminant tables there is one line for each form, containing 17 entries:

d   g   f11   f22   f33   f44   f12   f13   f23   f14   f24   f34   H   N   G   m1   m2  

where
      d = discriminant,
      g = identification number of genus to which f belongs,
      f11 ... f34 are the coefficients,
      H = Hasse symbol at all primes p dividing 2d, in increasing order of p (using 10 characters),
      N = level of   f = smallest N such that N F^(-1) has integer entries and even diagonal entries,
      G = number of automorphisms of   f,
      m1/m2 = the total mass of this genus
```

[Schiemann 1990](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01189584)
[image]

On positive binaries, Kaplansky and I collected all pairs of forms that simply agree on the primes represented, ignoring frequency of representation. [This was polished and corrected by John Voight, and published.](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu//~jvoight/articles/quadforms-mcom-fixed-errata-042512.pdf)

Comment: could you please include these two references in your answer?

Comment: @Tyrell put in some links to references, not sure what you wanted

Comment: Thanks, I was on page 36 and didn't realize that this question has already been answered in the book.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. So $N_f$ (the coefficients of the theta series) determinates $f$ (modulo $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$) a quadratic form in $n\le 3$  variables, but it is not true for quadratic forms in $4$ variables ?

Comment: @reuns, yes, that is about it. I put in a link for Schiemann's article on ternaries. His example in dimension 4 is available in many places, such as Nipp's book on quaternary forms. I pasted that in